# How to solve this optimization problem?

Tags: matrix, mathematical-optimization

Is there an effective method to solve the following optimization problem in Mathematica?

\begin{align*}
\min & \quad -t \\
\mathrm{s.t.} &\quad A \succeq  0,\,a=1
\end{align*}
I mean A is positive semidefinite.

The matrix $A$ is given:

```
A={{2 a^3-t,-12 a^3+3 a^2 b+15 a^2 c-8 c^3,2 u,2 v},{-12 a^3+3 a^2 b+15 a^2 c-8 c^3,-t-2 (8 a^3+36 a^2 b-3 a b^2-30 a b c-15 a c^2-15 a^2 d+24 c^2 d+2 u),-24 a^2 b-36 a b^2+b^3+15 b^2 c+15 b c^2+c^3+30 a b d+30 a c d-24 c d^2-2 v,2 w},{2 u,-24 a^2 b-36 a b^2+b^3+15 b^2 c+15 b c^2+c^3+30 a b d+30 a c d-24 c d^2-2 v,-t-2 (24 a b^2+12 b^3-15 b^2 d-30 b c d-3 c^2 d-15 a d^2+8 d^3+2 w),-8 b^3+15 b d^2+3 c d^2},{2 v,2 w,-8 b^3+15 b d^2+3 c d^2,2 d^3-t}}
```

Comment: You could provide details on $A(t)$

Comment: You don't have a matrix.  You have a matrix-valued function.  You don't even mention if this function is affine, as Roman claims.  Are you even trying?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo , I edited the question again.

Comment: It remains unsatisfactory.  Something satisfactory would be $A (t) := A_0 + t A_1$, where both $A_0$ and $A_1$ are symmetric.  In short, reading the Mathematica code should not be required in order to understand what $A (t)$ looks like.

Answer (score 5):

- If the "succeed equal to" $\succeq$  mean positive definite, we can consider the determinant of submatrix.
  $$\mathrm{Det} A(1,2,\cdots, k ; 1,2,\cdots,k)\geq 0$$

for all $1\leq k\leq n$

```
conditions = {Det[A[[Range@1, Range@1]]], Det[A[[Range@2, Range@2]]], 
    Det[A[[Range@3, Range@3]]], Det[A[[Range@4, Range@4]]]} >= 0;
sol = NMinimize[{-t, conditions}, {a, b, c, d, u, v, w, t}, 
  Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing"]
```

> `{0.00129277, {a -> -0.0646633, b -> -0.100358, c -> 0.1109,  d -> -0.0633609, u -> -0.000584144, v -> -0.0000168834,  w -> 0.0000766361, t -> -0.00129277}}`

```
conditions /. sol[[2]]
Eigenvalues[A /. sol[[2]]] > 0 // Thread
```

> `{True, True, True, True}`
> `{True, True, True, True}`

Comment: @Roman Thanks your example, it is actually need to add another extra conditions for the questionor's question.

Answer (score 1):

```
A = {{2 a^3 - t, -12 a^3 + 3 a^2 b + 15 a^2 c - 8 c^3, 2 u, 2 v},
     {-12 a^3 + 3 a^2 b + 15 a^2 c - 8 c^3, -t - 2 (8 a^3 + 36 a^2 b - 3 a b^2 - 30 a b c - 15 a c^2 - 15 a^2 d + 24 c^2 d + 2 u), -24 a^2 b - 36 a b^2 + b^3 + 15 b^2 c + 15 b c^2 + c^3 + 30 a b d + 30 a c d - 24 c d^2 - 2 v, 2 w},
     {2 u, -24 a^2 b - 36 a b^2 + b^3 + 15 b^2 c + 15 b c^2 + c^3 + 30 a b d + 30 a c d - 24 c d^2 - 2 v, -t - 2 (24 a b^2 + 12 b^3 - 15 b^2 d - 30 b c d - 3 c^2 d - 15 a d^2 + 8 d^3 + 2 w), -8 b^3 + 15 b d^2 + 3 c d^2},
     {2 v, 2 w, -8 b^3 + 15 b d^2 + 3 c d^2, 2 d^3 - t}} /. a -> 1;

NMinimize[{-t, VectorGreaterEqual[{A, 0}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 4}]},
          Variables[A], Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing"]

(*    {-0.368118, {b -> 0.320836, c -> 0.673546, d -> 1.42392, t -> 0.368118,
                   u -> -2.55571, v -> -0.698951, w -> -0.226576}}            *)
```

[`VectorGreaterEqual`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorGreaterEqual.html) looks better on the user interface:

[image]

Comment: Where does rule ` /. a -> 1` come  from?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann The question keeps changing and this condition has been added by the OP: minimize $A$ over the positive semidefinite cone with the constraint of $a=1$.

Comment: Thanks, change has passed me by